# Excide Battery manufacture date

Tags: battery

Can anyone tell me when my battery was manufactured.  It is an Exide 124R-60
Serial #2029261
The date is not punched out.  Help

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what country you buy it in what type of date code they use.

Date code is engraved or hot stamped into the battery case somewhere

This chart is for Automotive, Marine and Motorcycle batteries, but may apply to other types.

Yes they made a mistake on the chart, "explanation" section for Philippines and Korea are swapped

[image]

[Source](http://www.exidebatteries.com.au/battery-faq/)